# How to sequentially retrieve a list of short strings from long string in R?

Tags: r

Here is an example

```
x<-"ABCDEFGH"
x
[1] "ABCDEFGH"
```

My goal is to sequentially retrieve strings with `nchar=4` until to the end of `x`, thus the output would be:

```
> df
    xx
1 ABCD
2 BCDE
3 CDEF
4 DEFG
5 EFGH
```

Is there an easy way to reach it in R?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution where you just need to specify the number of characters you wish to extract from `x` as the `n` variable.

```
n<-4
sapply (1:(nchar(x)-(n-1)), function(i) substr(x,i,i+(n-1)))

#"ABCD" "BCDE" "CDEF" "DEFG" "EFGH"
```

Comment: This uses base R so you don't need to load stringr.

Comment: Ups, you are right, I forgot to delete that line. Already edited the post.

Comment: The output should all have 4 characters, but your output has mostly 5 characters

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach:

```
x<-"ABCDEFGH"

N <- 4

substring(x, seq(1, nchar(x)-N+1, 1), seq(N, nchar(x), 1))
[1] "ABCD" "BCDE" "CDEF" "DEFG" "EFGH"
```

Comment: `substring(x, 1:(nchar(x)-N+1), N:nchar(x))`. Same algorithm, simpler coding. But fails if `N > nchar(x)`. Upvote.